# Steps to Summation closed form

Tags: summation, geometric-series, summation-method

I have $$\sum_{n=1}^k 2^n$$
I got this result from trial and error (validated online), but I want to understand the steps to get there. $$= 2^{k+1}-2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), as each successive term is double the previous term.

You may know a general formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, or you can argue that this particular sum should have value $2^{k+1}-2$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
s=\sum_{i=1}^k 2^i&=2+4+8+\cdots+2^k\\
s&=2(1+2+4+\cdots+2^{k-1})\\
s&=2\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}2^i\right)\\
s/2-1+2^k&=\sum_{i=1}^k2^i\\
s/2-1+2^k&=s\\
2^k-1&=s/2\\
s&=2^{k+1}-2\end{align}$$

This proof generalises to give the general formula.